# Cypress net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE on real server calls

Tags: node.js, angular, testing, cypress, angular-e2e

I'm trying to test my fullstack angular-nestjs-application with cypress e2e tests.

Server calls from within angular **to not** reach my backend running on `localhost:443` (I tested it with `0.0.0.0`, `127.0.0.1` like some other answers requested - without success.
I also did try to add a local proxy on my machine like some other posts suggested - again without any success).

On the other hand: Requests sent by `cy.request('http://localhost:443/...'` do actually reach my backend. I am able to send the request in `beforeEach`, save the response, intercept the **real** request and feed the saved response data to it.

`cy.login()` does a login call to build a valid session for my backend.

```
    describe('test', () => {
        let data: any;

        beforeEach(() => {
            cy.login();
            cy.request('http://localhost:443/load').then(response => {
                data = response;
                console.log('BeforeEach Response: ', data);
            });
        });

        it('load data', () => {
            cy.visit('/');
        });
    });
```

[image]
[image]

But the following line in `beforeEach` does work:

```
cy.request('http://localhost:443/load').then(response => {
    data = response;
    console.log('BeforeEach Response: ', data);
});
```

[image]

So the following test does work completely:

```
    describe('test', () => {
        let data: any;

        beforeEach(() => {
            cy.login();
            cy.request('http://localhost:443/load').then(response => {
                data = response;
                console.log('BeforeEach Response: ', data);
            });
        });

        it('load data', () => {
            cy.intercept('/load', data);
            cy.visit('/');
        });
    });
```

[image]

So what am i missing to successfully test my application with real server requests - without sending the same request by hand and stubing the real one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your baseUrl in cypress.json is not `localhost:443`. If that's the case, then for chrome-based browsers you can set `chromeWebSecurity` to false. See https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/web-security#Set-chromeWebSecurity-to-false.
If that doesn't help or you have to test with firefox then you have to put your app and all required backend-services behind a proxy, so that it looks like every request is served by the proxy.
If you have Angular in dev-mode then you already have a proxy and you can configure your backend services via `proxy.conf.json`. See https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server

Comment: Thanks Man! Using the Angular Proxy works perfectly :)